# Postgres Function Slower than Query / Postgres 8.4

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I (must) use a Postgres 8.4 Database. In this Database i create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION counter (mindate timestamptz,maxdate timestamptz) RETURNS integer AS $func$ 
DECLARE result integer; 
BEGIN
Select INTO result COUNT(*) AS counter from columname where starttime BETWEEN $1 and $2;
Return result;  
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The Query:

```
apptelemetry=# select counter('2016-03-01 00:00:00','2016-03-11 00:00:00');
 requestcounter
----------------
           8893
(1 row)

Time: 4.740 ms
```

When i make a normal Query:

```
apptelemetry=# select Count(*) from columname where starttime BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-11 00:00:00';
 count
-------
  8893
(1 row)

Time: 3.214 ms
```

Why is the function slower than the normal query? Have someone performance tips for me?

Regrads

Comment: this happen if you run the same query several times? and do you have index for `starttime` because this shouldnt be so slow no matter the order.

Comment: You don't really need `PL/pgSQL` for this. The 1ms overhead could well be caused by the overhead of calling PL/pgSQL. What happens if you change that to a simple `language sql` function?

Comment: "Why is the function slower than the normal query?" --- why should a function be faster? Just because you have wrapped something into a function does not make it faster automagically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The queries in PLpgSQL are blindly optimized. Sometimes a execution plan can be suboptimal for some parameters.

The PLpgSQL reuses execution plan of any query. It has some advantages (there are no repeated expensive query planning), but it has some disadvantages too (the plan is not optimized for real values, it is optimized for the most probably values). The modern versions of Postgres are little bit smarter.

The solution of this query is dynamic SQL. In this case the execution plan is not reused, and then can be optimized for real parameter's values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION counter (mindate timestamptz,maxdate timestamptz) RETURNS integer AS $func$ 
DECLARE result integer; 
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM columname 
             WHERE starttime BETWEEN $1 and $2'
     INTO result USING mindate, maxdate;
  RETURN result;  
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

One article about this issue: http://blog.endpoint.com/2008/12/why-is-my-function-slow.html

Comment: Thank you very much! :-) Works a much better than mine!

Comment: Downvoted, since custom plans in prepared statements (functions) is fixed since postgresql 9.2. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Upvoted, since changing an `SQL` function to a `plpgsql` implementation using `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '...' USING` helped to speed up my query 10 times (with PostgreSQL 11.1). So this answer really helped me.

Comment: @ElgerMensonides - Unfortunately, it was not fixed (I think so it is not principally possible). There is just new heuristic, that try to be little bit smarter (first 5 iterations uses custom plan, others depends on cost decisions), but there are reports so this design doesn't work 100% well.  This heuristic is too simple, and cannot to work well for all cases.

Answer (score 4):

A PL/pgSQL function has overhead for setting up its environment. In your case, however, you could use a SQL language function which is much more efficient:

```
CREATE FUNCTION counter (mindate timestamptz, maxdate timestamptz) RETURNS integer AS
$func$ 
  SELECT count(*) FROM columname WHERE starttime BETWEEN $1 AND $2;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Only when you need functionality that is not supported by the SQL language, like conditional branching, should you use PL/pgSQL.

That said, actual run times can be influenced by many things inside or outside of the DBMS so a simple comparison of a single run may be impacted by such influences.

Comment: In this case plpgsql has not to have any overhead,